# Export to Excel/print HTML table with gridlines

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an HTML table in my ASP.NET MVC project that can be exported to Excel or printed using some JavaScript I found online. Both of these features export/print the table without gridlines, which makes the data very hard to read especially when there's significant amounts of text in a cell.

The table is wrapped in a `div#table-wrapper`, and `#printer` and `#excel` are small icons that when clicked print/export the table. Here is the JavaScript:

```
$("#printer").on("click", function () {
    var divToPrint = document.getElementById('table-wrapper');
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
    newWin.print();
    newWin.close();
});

$("#excel").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var table_div = document.getElementById('table-wrapper');
    var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
    a.download = 'exported_table_' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 9999999 + 1000000) + '.xls';
    a.click();
});
```

Here's a picture of the spreadsheet:
[image: This is a picture of the exported Excel spreadsheet]

Here's a picture of the print preview:
[image: This is a picture of the print preview]

If someone knows how I can add gridlines to these that would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**: I've added this stylesheet to my project and still have no luck on the print table.

```
@media print {
    th, td {
        border: 1px solid #000;
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
}
```

**EDIT #2:** Here's the table.

```
<div id="table-wrapper">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="results-grid">
        <thead>
            <tr id="results-heading">
                <th>Submission #</th>
                <th>First Named Insured</th>
                <th>Status</th>
                <th>TA Name</th>
                <th>Policy #</th>
                <th>Branch</th>
                <th>Underwriter</th>
                <th>Division</th>
                <th>Project Name</th>
                <th>Project Address</th>
                <th>Project City/State/Zip</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        @if (Model.Projects.Any())
        {
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Projects)
                {
                <tr data-id="@item.id" data-subNum="@item.submission_number" data-readOnly="@Model.ReadOnly" class="clickable-row">
                    @if (Model.Cleared)
                    {
                        <td><a onclick="displayDetails(@item.id)">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.submission_number)</a></td>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.submission_number)</td>
                    }
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.first_named_insured)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.status)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ta_name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.policy_number)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.branch)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.underwriter)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.division)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project_name)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project_address)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project_city), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project_state), @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.project_zip_code)</td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        }
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using CSS media queries to specify print styles?

Answer (score 0):

As Mark mentioned in the comments, you can use media queries for different media types. Here's the syntax to add to your CSS stylesheet:

```
@media print {
/* CSS code that adds lines or bottom border to table */
}
```

You can also have different stylesheets for different media by defining them in the head of your html like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="print" href="print.css">
```

Comment: I tried that before and it didn't work but I tried again just to see if I made a mistake and no luck this time either. I've edited my post with the CSS code, let me know if you see any glaring errors :)

Comment: Got it -- try adding !important; after your css lines, does that do it?

Comment: Can you add your html?

Comment: Just added it but it's really just a table, not much to it.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to the fact that there's no CSS (#bootstrap) at the print page "it clearly has no business with your current page since its a new tab". So try modifying it say like this:

```
newWin = window.open("");
var htx = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://location_of_css" />';
htx += divToPrint.outerHTML;
newWin.document.write(htx);
newWin.print();
```

Hope it helps